# GCP composer environment - not able to create the environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

can someone help in fixing the bug? not sure why I keep getting the following error

```
{
 insertId:  "5trpe7fxgu9l7"   
 logName:  "projects/spikey-gcp-262519/logs/composer-agent"   
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-12-20T02:32:00.386354407Z"   
 resource: {…}   
 severity:  "ERROR"   
 textPayload:  "Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
"   
 timestamp:  "2019-12-20T02:31:27.709767814Z"   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the command used it's complicated to know the cause of the issue; nevertheless, for the "textPayload" this could be related with an issue with the permissions of the service account that tried to create the Composer Cluster.

I suggest you to verify the permissions needed to [create](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#access-control) Composer Environment and how to [grant access to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts). If this does not work please share the command used to create the environment.